# Where do the Breen come from? Does Their alliance border the Cardassian Union?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9

I was looking at a cool map of the Alpha quadrant someone else posted and I couldn't find the Breen.

Comment: Bear in mind that Star Trek, in general, does not have a super-detailed sense of galactic geography.

Comment: Paul D. Waite - "That much is certain".  In fact I hope to write a book about the "galactography" of Star Trek.  (Isaac Asimov used the word "galactography" in his "empire" novels).

Comment: Can you post a link to said map?

Answer (score 5):

According to the excellent [Star Trek: Star Charts](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_Star_Charts) The Breen Confederacy is on the left hand side of the Cardassian Union, away from the Federation. It doesn't appear to share any common borders with the Federation.

[image]

[image]